# PowerShell Hash of Hashes how to change the values?

Tags: powershell, hash

I have a hash of hashes:

```
 $h1 = @{
    "h2" = @{
        "key1" = 1
        "key2" = 2
        "key3" = 3
        "key4" = 4
    }
 }
```

I can access and get the keys and values:

```
$n = 10
ForEach($r in $h1.h2.GetEnumerator()) {
    Write-Host "$($r.Name)$($r.Value)" # ok
    $h1.h2.$($r.Name) = $n # Error
    $n++
}
```

But I cannot change the values to $n - how do I do that with this loop?

```
ForEach($r in $h1.h2.GetEnumerator()) {
    Write-Host "$($r.Name)$($r.Value)" # want to see new values 10, 11, 12, ...
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Gooly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate just the key names, and use that for your loop enumeration:

```
$h1 = @{
    "h2" = @{
        "key1" = 1
        "key2" = 2
        "key3" = 3
        "key4" = 4
    }
 }

$n = 10
ForEach($r in $h1.h2.GetEnumerator() | select -ExpandProperty name) {
    Write-Host "$r$($h1.h2.$r)" # ok
    $h1.h2.$r = $n
    $n++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$h1 = @{
"h2" = @{
    "key1" = 1
    "key2" = 2
    "key3" = 3
    "key4" = 4
}
}


$n = 10
$h3 = @{}
ForEach($r in $h1.h2.Keys) {
Write-Host "$r" 
$h3.Add("$($r)", $n)
$n++

}

ForEach($r in $h3.GetEnumerator()) {
Write-Host "$($r.Name)$($r.Value)" # want to see new values 10, 11, 12, ...
}
```

Comment: Be careful with that.  If that hash table has a key named 'keys' it will all go sideways.

Comment: Ah thank you, I did not know about that, I thought Keys was a keyword.

Comment: Nope. There's nothing to stop you from using 'keys' as a key name, and if you do $ht.keys will start to return the value of that entry, not the key collection.  If you're not sure that will never be a key value, then use .getenumerator() and grab the names. That always works.